# like() got an unexpected keyword argument 'story_id'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Episode has GenericRelation with Like model

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    likes = GenericRelation(Like)
```

Viewset:

```
class EpisodeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, LikedMixin):
    serializer_class = EpisodeSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Episode.objects.filter(story=self.kwargs.get('story_id'))

        return queryset
```

urls:

```
router.register(r'(?P<story_id>\d+)/episodes', views.EpisodeViewSet, basename='episodes')
```

LikedMixin has function for performing like action:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
def like(self, request, pk=None):
    obj = self.get_object()
    services.add_like(obj, request.user)

    return Response()
```

When I try post request with url `0.0.0.0:3000/stories/1/episodes/1/like/`, i recieve error 
like() got an unexpected keyword argument 'story_id'.

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        if isinstance(obj, (Story,)):
            return obj.author == request.user
        elif isinstance(obj, (Episode,)):
            return obj.story.author == request.user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this..

```
   @action(detail=True, methods=['POST'])
   def like(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
       obj = self.get_object()
       services.add_like(obj, request.user)

       return Response()
```

Comment: now, i have another problem, this is 'post' request and if user wants to like other's episode, it goes to permission(added in question), and return that i cant, how to avoid this

Comment: maybe you can pass another permission class to the action decorator..?